# calling nested javascript function in django template

Tags: javascript, django-templates

I am new to both Django and Javascript and am having trouble calling a user defined function from within a javascript function in Django template.

I have a javascript block as follows:

```
function EditDialog(pk) {       
   $.ajax({
       url: "{% url 'populatereviewform' %}",
       method: 'GET',
       data: {
       pk: pk
       },
       success: function(formHtml){
          //Do something
          alert("Success!")
       },
       dataType: 'html'
    });

    // this is my function that I would like to call
    function MyFunc(e, offset) {
       alert("Calling my function")
    }

    // Now I try to call this function from another function
    ("#dialog").submit(function(e)
    {
        this.MyFunc(e, "1");
        return false;
    });
}
```

My question is how can I call this nested function?
In the code above, I am creating a function called `MyFunc` which I am trying to call from the submit method. However, this comes back with `this.MyFunc is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` is bound to something else.

Remove `this` and call your function like this: `MyFunc()`.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned it, but that does not work. I get the same error without the `this`.

Comment: You also need to add the ```$``` on ```$("#dialog")```